# CSS3 @media Rule behaving odd on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have this code on my site to hide content when in desktop view:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px), only screen and (min-device-width: 767px) {
  .hide-desktop {
    display:none!important;
  }
}
```

But for some reason its hiding when I'm on mobile and in developer tools it shows when I remove the class. It seemed to work fine in the past with other things I've done but for this.

Comment: Check support for (min-)device-width / -height/ -aspect-ratio as they are deprecated and add example code so we can see how your CSS is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!important`, as it can cause other CSS properties to misbehave from the usual flow and makes it hard to detect any sort of bugs.

Then,
Check in developer tools that rather any other CSS property is overwriting it.

If none of the above is working for you, post your whole HTML and CSS so we can help further.